# Error after installing .apk in android device

Tags: android, device, apk

I have developed one Android application. I have installed the .apk in Samsung Galaxy Pop. It has installed successfully but when I'm trying to open it, it gives me an error "Application is unexpectedly close". The application works fine on emulator. I don't know what is the problem. Please someone give me proper suggestions regarding it.

Comment: You mean to say error???

Comment: Dr.nik this is one big application i am not able to put whole code here. Error is same as written in question. i can post manifest file though. If you want.

Comment: you can past first logcat and then related file

Comment: cant you see the line where it does occur in logcat????

Comment: may i know where is log cat in android device?

Comment: you have to connect the device to the pc so you can see the logcat of your device in ECLIPSE while keep USB debugging mode of your device is on....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
first of all check screen sizes in manifest..
check all permissions ur application need is added in ur manifest?
check versions supported by your application..

<uses-permission />
<permission />
<permission-tree />
<permission-group />
<instrumentation />
<uses-sdk />
<uses-configuration />  
<uses-feature />  
<supports-screens />  
<compatible-screens />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, post your code here:

-> Activity launcher

-> XML's Activity launcher

-> Android Manifest

> Blockquote

Check these things:

-> All of Jigar Patel wrote, and:

-> Make sure that the Launcher Activity has declared in Mainfest.

-> Check your package in Mainfest

-> Permissions

Put your error log here, because there are a lot of possibilities to solve.
Is your error about library? You have to check your build path library.

But, if your error (in a logcat) is about "NullpointerException", try to correct your code.